# Setup unit testing with Jenkins CI for a Maven project

Tags: git, unit-testing, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

For some reason I'm having a hard time understanding unit testing using Jenkins CI for a "Maven managed project". My goal is to pull my Maven project from `git`, build it, unit test it, and if all goes right, deploy it. I managed to achieve every step except the unit test step. I have no idea where to start or what to change. I think the basic idea is to have Unit tests in the `maven` project and trigger the Unit tests through Jenkins. But how? What do I need to change/add to my Maven project? And how do I trigger the unit test from Jenkins and how does Jenkins know the test results?

Every document/tutorial seems to skip basic steps and gets me lost. The tutorials seem to teach what you can do but not how.

Are there any good tutorials for beginners I'm missing? Or can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `maven-surefire-plugin` in your `pom.xml`. Then regular maven build will execute the tests as well (as part of the entire build procedure) and generate report files to be displayed by Jenkins.

Comment: Is it really as simple as adding the right lines in pom.xml and surefire plugin searches and finds the unit tests and runs them in the build phase of the project? Or do i have to somehow point to the unit test files?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Surefire plugin joins to test phase at maven build lifecycle and searches for tests in default location (module/src/test/java). Also you need to have junit in module dependencies (test scope is fine).

Comment: Actions above will fail build on test failure. To see reports in Jenkins you also need open job configuration Post-build actions and check "Publish JUnit test result report" and input "**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml" if it is not already out-of-the-box.

Comment: I don't have the option "Publish JUnit test result report" in a "Build a maven project" job, but i do have the option in "Freestyle project".